# How to get the pgfplots external tutorial to work in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

In 7.1.1 of the PGFPLOTS library the following example of externalization is given. Whatever I try, I cannot get it to work in TeXniccenter, running MiKTeX 2.8.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize% activate externalization!

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Our first external graphics example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I tried adding the following command line arguments to the output profile

```
-shell-escape -synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%bm"
```

And tried a number of other things, but I cannot get it to work. 
Error:

Package TiKz error: Sorry the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "plaatje-figure0" ...
did NOT result in a usable output file 'plaatje-figure0'

Comment: I think in MikTeX you have to compile with `-enable-write18` instead of `-shell-escape`. So try changing that in the command line arguments and in the TeX file (`\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]`)

Comment: Note, that did not make a change. But updating to MiKTeX 2.9 did. Don't know why, though?

Comment: I still cannot get my head around the fact that MiKTeX 2.8 would not work? I Downloaded PGF from the repository. Is the repository not updated for a fixed version of MiKTEX?

Comment: @willem Have a look at the MikTeX manual and the release note for version 2.9. Maybe you find an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating the MikTeX installation would solve the issue as I'm using the same configuration

[image]
And the result is

[image]